# unicode not showing properly

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

> I'm creating an app in flash cc. In my app, I need to show some
>   unicode text(devanagari text) which I get from the server.

**Problem**:

> It is showing on textfield but the problem is with the half letters. 
>   The words like `प्रजनन्`is displayed `प् रजनन्`. It works fine on
>   computer but problem only occurs on android devices. Does any one
>   knows why it's not working on android devices?

**Note:**
I think the computer knows `प्र`is a single word even if it consist of 3 unicode character `\u092a\u094d\u0930` but the devices seems to take it as separate letters. I've been searching for answer on google with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should embed the entire font (or at least all the characters you are going to use) you are using.

Comment: I did. But still don't work.

Comment: Hmmm... Kerning?

Comment: Also, did you try varying AIR version? Like 21-23-25?

Comment: Yes, I did try different AIR version. Also didn't work.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm out of ideas for the moment **(>_<)**

Comment: Is there a way to convert the unicode back to normal text ?

Comment: What's "normal text" anyway? Flash works with unicode by default. As soon as you assign **var S:String = "Это русский текст.";** you get a unicode string, which might (or might) take more than one byte.

Comment: I mean `प्र` is devanagari text and it's unicode value is `\u092a\u094d\u0930`. `प्र` is written in font called `preeti`. It, then converted into unicode to store in server. Can I convert `\u092a\u094d\u0930` to it's original form `प्र` which if type on any english font will be `k|`.

Comment: Ah. Well. You can try 2 things: (1) **ByteArray.writeUTFBytes("प्र");** then work with the bytes, just don't forget that first 3 bytes will be a BOM prefix (UTF-8 BOM, I think), or (2) work with **Srting.charCodeAt(index:uint):uint** then **String.fromCharCode(value:uint):String**.

Comment: Hi. I stumbled across this today. Have you tried using device fonts instead of embedding your font? https://snag.gy/6RnwBg.jpg

Comment: @quantomworks Are you sure some weird font will be installed on a random mobile device?

Comment: @Organis Hmm... Good point.. maybe for Indian users ...

Comment: @quantomworks using device fonts doesn't work

Comment: @Organis I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: @Organis Does above code you mentioned convert `\u092a\u094d\u0930` to `k|`?

Comment: @TheGunners How did you decide it is "k|"? 2A = *, 4D = M, 30 = 0, look here: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: @Organis first `प्र` is written in font preeti which is `k|` in other english fonts. But it is converted into unicode later to store in server. If you type `k|` in any font and change font to devanagari , it should show `प्र` in most of the devenagari font.